# "gzserver: symbol lookup error" when launching Gazebo in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sdformat, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have just installed ROS kinetic and Gazebo 7.12.0 in Ubuntu 16.04. When I launch `gazebo` from terminal I get the following error:

```
gzserver: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsdformat.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZN8ignition4math15SemanticVersionC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

and Gazebo won't start.

The strange thing is that if I launch the Turtlebot simulation `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch` Gazebo starts correctly without raising any error. Any idea on why this is happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19156/%22gzserver:-symbol-lookup-error%22-when-launching-gazebo-in-ubuntu-16.04/) by [gianluca](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5066/gianluca/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I solved a similar problem using the solution here - https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2448/problem-running-gazebo7
Check if that solves it.

---

Originally posted by [parthchopra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5566/parthchopra/) with karma: 16 on 2018-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rajshah1993](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14723/rajshah1993/) on 2020-05-31**:
hi @parthchopra, I dont know why but I cant access the link which you mentioned. Could you provide another reference on how did you solved this problem? Thanks.